# Is mixed per-mode possible in SIunitx?

Tags: siunitx

In spectroscopy, frequency is often expressed as wavenumbers, which are reciprocal centimeters (I have `\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\per\cm}` in my standard preamble). I would like to show the shift in frequency of a laser as a function of temperature, whose units should look like `cm$^{-1}$/K` but always either comes out `/cm/K` or `cm$^{-1}$ K$^{-1}$`. While I realize that all are technically mathematically correct (which is the best kind of correct), it is less ambiguous and customary in the field to distinguish between wavenumbers as a frequency and inverse length by writing the units as in the first case.

Is it possible to tell `SIunitx`, perhaps as part of the declare unit command, that the exponent should be treated as part of the unit always, even if the per-mode is changed?

Comment: Can you point to an online source where the requested output is used?

Comment: The best example that I'm familiar with is the [HITRAN](http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/hitran/FAQ.html) spectroscopic database. The units for the intensity are given as wavenumbers per molecule per square centimeter. Mathematically, you could combine the the frequency and area to get a unit of per molecule per volume, but because the distances arise from two different physical quantities, you lose descriptive physical meaning by doing so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define `\wn` slightly different using `siunitx`' `\tothe` or `\raiseto`:

```
\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\raiseto{-1}\cm}
```

or

```
\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\cm\tothe{-1}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit\wn{\cm\tothe{-1}}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}

\si{\wn\per\kelvin}

\end{document}
```

[image]