# "Package siunitx Error: Duplicate \per" with \DeclareSIUnit

Tags: siunitx

The following gets me this error

> Package siunitx Error: Duplicate \per

The desired output is `N.m/(rad.s-1)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\hspace{-0.5ex}}\cdot{\hspace{-0.5ex}}},
    sticky-per,
    per-mode = symbol,
    bracket-unit-denominator,
}
\DeclareSIUnit[per-mode = reciprocal-positive-first]{\radpers}{\radian\per\s}
\begin{document}
    \si{\N\m\per\radpers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try changing `\si{\N\m\per\radpers}` to `\si{\N\m\per(\radpers)}`.

Comment: @Mico The output would be forced into the literal mode as shown here https://ibb.co/TgBDLCr whithout even the desired result.

Comment: You've set `sticky-per`, which means you can only have _one_ `\per` in the entire unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `sticky-per`, which means that `\per` is automatically applied to every unit after the first one. You have *two* `\per` in `\N\m\per\radpers`, as this becomes (effectively) `\N\m\per\radian\per\s`. You would see exactly the same error if you used that input directly. You need to turn off `sticky-per`.

(I personally do not like `sticky-per`: it is included in the package only as some users feel this is more 'logical'.)

Comment: I thought that the definition of the declared unit `\radpers` and its options won't be expanded.

Comment: @Diaa No, the way things work is units are parsed to give an internal representation, then re-constructed based on the output settings. That's why I said `\N\m\per\radpers` is 'effectively' `\N\m\per\radian\per\s`: in reality it's not the same.

Comment: But if I removed `sticky-per`, I would get `N.m/(rad.s)`, which means that the option `per-mode = reciprocal-positive-first` of `\DeclareSIUnit` has no effect at all. Is it intended to work like this to ignore all the options of `\DeclareSIUnit`? In other words, when do the options of `\DeclareSIUnit` affect the declared unit?

Comment: @Diaa No, the options always apply to the unit _as a whole_: as I said, what happens is everything is pared then re-combined. I get the odd question about this, but I've never seen a typeset publication where people use this 'mixed' style of unit presentation.

Answer (score 0):

[A relevant answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182797/2288) suggested using `\raiseto{-1}` or `\tothe{-1}` instead of `\per\` with `\DeclareSIUnit`.

However, I don't know if the error is a result of a wrong syntax or a bug.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    load-configurations = abbreviations,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{\hspace{-0.5ex}}\cdot{\hspace{-0.5ex}}},
    sticky-per,
    per-mode = symbol,
    bracket-unit-denominator,
}
\DeclareSIUnit{\radpers}{\radian\s\tothe{-1}}
\begin{document}
    \si{\N\m\per\radpers}
\end{document}
```